# Highlighting differences in child values for parent values in OBIEE or SQL

Tags: sql, obiee

[image: Question Diagram]

I can't seem to figure out how to select instances where values in the green circle would be highlighted/selected for every parent/orange-circle value. What would this sort of operation be called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to translate that into an understandable requirement: You want to select (means filter for) "Load IDs" which have more than 1 "Purchase Order Numbers"?

That's what it reads to me from your data grid because the PO Number is the one that changes the query grain and causes two rows. Everything else is the same.

If that's the case then create a measure which counts the PO Numbers and filter on that.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. How would I be able to detect a mismatch between the green circles values though?

Comment: Same way. Count distinct dwell time. if that count > 1, colour. Granted this is onyl for your data grid above and not really a generic approach since OBI doen't work with SQL queries, but data models and result sets.